# can anyone explain what does this loop if(month%3==0 && day>=21) doing

Tags: java

I did not understand what the if loop is trying to do.Can anyone explain me.why are the months re-initialized again using the dates?

```
    if (month <= 3){
        season = "winter";
    }

    else if (month <= 6){
        season = "spring";
    }

    else if (month <= 9){
        season = "summer";
    }

    else if (month <= 12){
        season = "fall";
    }

    if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21)
    {
        if (season == "winter")
            season = "spring";
            }
        else if (season == "spring"){
            season = "summer";
            }
        else if (season == "summer"){
            season = "fall";
            }
        else {
            season = "winter";
            }
```

Comment: That's not a loop.

Comment: And there's no such thing as an "if loop". Loops repeat, and an if block doesn't.

Comment: Also, don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: This code is ugly and likely wrong given the object equality `==` used on strings. I suggest you not try to understand it.

Comment: Seasons don't always change on the 21st (local date), but could be the 20th or 22nd depending on where you are on the Earth's surface and where we are in the leap-year cycle.  The only way to be absolutely certain is to use an astronomical reference and adjust for your local timezone.  Also, this is very ugly code, even if you ignore the string comparison errors/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The algorithm seems to try to achieve the following:

21 dec - 20 mar: winter

21 mar - 20 jun: spring

21 jun - 20 sep: summer

21 sep - 20 dec: fall

The months are reassigned to account for the fact that the seasons change in the middle of the month (the 21st instead of the 1st). If the seasons were to change exactly at the 1st day of the month, the if block in question would not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The first set of ifs establishes the Season based on a given month.
Since the seasons start at 21st, the second set of IFs verifies wether it's already the next season or not.

If month mod 3 == 0 means that this is a season shifting month and it must consider the day.

Answer (score 0):

The [solstices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solstice) and [equinoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox) occur on the 21st of March, June, September, and December, hence the line `if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21)`.

For example, during the month of June, days 1-20 are technically in the season of spring. However, on June 21 and forward, the days are technically summer. The lines of code in question serve to rectify the fact that not all months (March, June, September, and December) are completely in one season.

**EDIT:**

The lines here:

```
if (season == "winter"){
    season = "spring";
}
else if (season == "spring"){
    season = "summer";
}
else if (season == "summer"){
    season = "fall";
}
else {
    season = "winter";
}
```

serve to "push" to the next season, since the top half of the code would set June 25 to "spring", when it should really be "summer".